# Call functions from function inside an object in a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, call

I have a javascript object with some functions inside, I wish I could call them in a loop, something like this:

```
funcs: {
  func1: function() {
      return true;
  },
  func2: function() {
      return false;
  }
}

for(func in funcs) {
   console.log(funcs[func]());
   console.log(funcs[func].call());
}
```

Comment: your wish is granted (i.e. that code works)

Comment: which one of them I'm curiour -> the .call() or the()

Comment: both work fine. I don't really know the difference though.

Comment: They both work (change to `var funcs = {...}`).  The second version will default the context to the global object unless an object instance is passed in as the first parameter: `funcs[func].call(funcs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work. But the declaration of your object is not correct. It is `var object = { /*something*/};`

```
var funcs = {
  func1: function() {
      return true;
  },
  func2: function() {
      return false;
  }
};

for(func in funcs) {
   console.log(funcs[func]());
   console.log(funcs[func].call());
}
```

Output

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: Here you can loop with `for(func in obj.funcs) {}`

Comment: what is `obj`? There is no object or variable called `obj` here.

Comment: I was answering to a comment that apparently has been deleted.